# MySQL ORDER BY Column = value AND distinct?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic, field, sql-order-by

I'm getting grey hair by now...

I have a table like this.

```
ID - Place - Person
1 - London - Anna
2 - Stockholm - Johan
3 - Gothenburg - Anna
4 - London - Nils
```

And I want to get the result where all the different persons are included, but I want to choose which Place to order by.

For example. I want to get a list where they are ordered by LONDON and the rest will follow, but distinct on PERSON.

```
Output like this:
ID - Place - Person
1 - London - Anna
4 - London - Nils
2 - Stockholm - Johan
```

Tried this:

```
SELECT ID, Person
FROM users        
ORDER BY FIELD(Place,'London'), Person ASC "
```

But it gives me:

```
ID - Place - Person
1 - London - Anna
4 - London - Nils
3 - Gothenburg - Anna
2 - Stockholm - Johan
```

And I really dont want Anna, or any person, to be in the result more then once.

Comment: +1. This is a deceptively non-trivial specification, returning only one row per `Person`; ensuring that the row is a `'Place='London'` row  if it exists, otherwise, some other row. It seems simple enough a specification, but the actual implementation will give you gray hair! Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have analytic functions like other RDBMS, but one option is to emulate a "ROW_NUMBER" analytic function. The SQL to do that isn't very straight forward. (See my answer for an example of that approach.)

Comment: Can "London - Anna" appear more than once?

Comment: @Strawberry No, the whole idea is to only have a person once with the twist to sort they by one place first. Then the rest of the people will follow in ASC order.

Comment: I mean in the data set. Not the result set.

Comment: @Strawberry Oh. My bad. "London - Anna" will only appear once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to get the specified output, but this uses MySQL specific behavior which is not guaranteed:

```
SELECT q.ID
     , q.Place
     , q.Person
  FROM ( SELECT IF(p.Person<=>@prev_person,0,1) AS r
              , @prev_person := p.Person AS person
              , p.Place
              , p.ID
           FROM users p
          CROSS
           JOIN (SELECT @prev_person := NULL) i  
          ORDER BY p.Person, !(p.Place<=>'London'), p.ID
       ) q
 WHERE q.r = 1
ORDER BY !(q.Place<=>'London'), q.Person
```

This query uses an inline view to return all the rows in a particular order, by Person, so that all of the 'Anna' rows are together, followed by all the 'Johan' rows, etc. The set of rows for each person is ordered by, `Place='London'` first, then by ID.

The "trick" is to use a MySQL user variable to compare the values from the current row with values from the previous row. In this example, we're checking if the 'Person' on the current row is the same as the 'Person' on the previous row. Based on that check, we return a 1 if this is the "first" row we're processing for a a person, otherwise we return a 0.

The outermost query processes the rows from the inline view, and excludes all but the "first" row for each Person (the 0 or 1 we returned from the inline view.)

(This isn't the only way to get the resultset. But this is one way of emulating analytic functions which are available in other RDBMS.)

---

For comparison, in databases *other* than MySQL, we could use SQL something like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Person ORDER BY 
         CASE WHEN t.Place='London' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, t.ID) AS rn
      , t.ID
      , t.Place
      , t.Person
   FROM users t
  WHERE rn=1
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.Place='London' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, t.Person
```

---

**Followup**

At the beginning of the answer, I referred to MySQL behavior that was not guaranteed. I was referring to the usage of MySQL User-Defined variables within a SQL statement.

Excerpts from MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html

"As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement."

"For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed."

"the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined."

Comment: This solved the problem. On first glance it seems like something easy to pull off. But it really is not. Thanks for good solution and explaination.

Comment: You have an ORDER BY (and no grouping), so I think this *is* guaranteed !?!

Comment: @Strawberry: What's _not_ guaranteed by MySQL is the order of evaluation of the expressions involving MySQL user-defined variables. The documentation includes a warning about this, and says the order of evaluation is "undefined". The SELECT statement in my answer _depends_ on the order of evaluation of those expressions. We observe that the approach does work, and that the behavior is repeatable; it's just not "guaranteed" by MySQL.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know that - although I do vaguely remember an article pointing out idiosyncrasies of variables

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `group by` instead of `distinct`:

```
SELECT ID, Person
FROM users   
GROUP BY ID, Person     
ORDER BY MAX(FIELD(Place, 'London')), Person ASC;
```

The `GROUP BY` does the same thing as `SELECT DISTINCT`.  But, you are allowed to mention other fields in clauses such as `HAVING` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I can see this query works with the sample data, but if we were to add a row `5 - Vienna - Anna`, I don't think this would return the desired  result. (Using the `MAX()` aggregate as the way identify `London` just doesn't seem like the right way to go.)

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . "Duh".  I get what you are saying now and fix the answer.  I missed that the sample data had duplicate Annas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, Place, Person
FROM users
GROUP BY Person
ORDER BY FIELD(Place,'London') DESC, Person ASC;
```

Comment: @spencer7593: Have you seen the "GROUP BY Person"? Do you have an example where this doesn't work?

Comment: The result returned by this query doesn't match the specification. It can return a row other than a 'London' row for a given Person. (Since the `ORDER BY` is processed _after_ the `GROUP BY` clause, there is no guarantee that the 'London' row will be the one returned. SQL Fiddle demonstration of this query behavior (returning a row other than the 'London' row) is here: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65fc1/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65fc1/1)